# nodejs with supertest, calling an endpoint twice for different test cases getting a Did you forget to wait for something async in your test?

Tags: node.js, jestjs, supertest, fast-csv

i have a single endpoint where i call twice on 2 different describes to test different responses

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const fs = require("fs");
const multer = require("multer");
const upload = multer({ dest: "files/" });
const csv = require("fast-csv");

let response = { message: "success" }
router.post("/post_file", upload.single("my_file"), (req, res) => {
    let output = get_output(req.file.path);
    fs.unlinkSync(req.file.path);

    if(output.errors.length > 0) response.message = "errors found";

    res.send(JSON.stringify(response))
})


const get_output = (path) => {

  let errors = []
  let fs_stream = fs.createReadStream(path);
  let csv_stream = csv.parse().on("data", obj => {
                   if(!is_valid(obj)) errors.push(obj);
            });
  

  fs_stream.pipe(csv_stream);

  return {errors};
}

const is_valid = (row) => {
   console.log("validate row")
   
   // i validate here and return a bool
}
```

my unit tests

```
const app = require("../server");
const supertest = require("supertest");
const req = supertest(app);

describe("parent describe", () => {

  describe("first call", () => {   
      const file = "my path to file"

      // this call succeeds
    it("should succeed", async (done) => {
      let res = await req
        .post("/post_file")
        .attach("my_file", file);
     
      expect(JSON.parse(res.text).message).toBe("success")
      done();
     });
   })

    describe("second call", () => {   
      const file = "a different file"

    // this is where the error starts
    it("should succeed", async (done) => {
      let res = await req
        .post("/post_file")
        .attach("my_file", file);
     
      expect(JSON.parse(res.text).message).toBe("errors found")
      done();
     });
   })
})

// csv file is this

NAME,ADDRESS,EMAIL
Steve Smith,35 Pollock St,ssmith@emailtest.com
```

I get the following

Cannot log after tests are done. Did you forget to wait for something async in your test?
Attempted to log "validate row".

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't mix `async` and `done`, it's either one or another, preferably the former. And the problem is that `/post_file` works incorrectly, it's asynchronous but it responds synchronously with wrong response because it doesn't wait for `get_output`.

Comment: @EstusFlask so how do i make it wait? do i just make it a promise?

Comment: Yes, promisify /post_file route and a stream in get_output.

Comment: Do you mind writing a snippet of that? I'm a little new to node and still getting a hang of it. Thanks

Comment: To promisify a stream, you need to know what events it supports. I can't write a snippet without knowing what is `csv` and how it works.

Comment: it's fast-csv. ive updated the question with the complete dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that tested route is incorrectly implemented, it works asynchronously but doesn't wait for `get_output` to end and responds synchronously with wrong response. The test just reveals that `console.log` is asynchronously called after test end.

Consistent use of promises is reliable way to guarantee the correct execution order. A stream needs to be promisified to be chained:

```
router.post("/post_file", upload.single("my_file"), async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    let output = await get_output(req.file.path);
    ...
    res.send(JSON.stringify(response))
  } catch (err) {
    next(err)
  }
})    

const get_output = (path) => {
  let errors = []
  let fs_stream = fs.createReadStream(path);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let csv_stream = csv.parse()
    .on("data", obj => {...})
    .on("error", reject)
    .on("end", () => resolve({errors}))
  });
}
```

`async` and `done` shouldn't be mixed in tests because they serve the same goal, this may result in test timeout if `done` is unreachable:

```
it("should succeed", async () => {
  let res = await req
    .post("/post_file")
    .attach("my_file", file);
 
  expect(JSON.parse(res.text).message).toBe("success")
});
```